# Entire hash getting returned at the end of the loop

Tags: ruby

**Code**

```
$dail_book = { 
  "los_angeles" => 212,
  "new_york" => 523,
  "portland" => 234,
  "seattle" => 502,
  "miami" => 910,
  "san_francisco" => 345,
  "sioux_falls" => 543,
  "omaha" => 642,
  "minneapolis" => 342,
  "san_diego" => 233
}

# Removes the underscore, captalizes each city,
# and prints it back to the user
def format_cities(k)
  puts "#{k.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')}"
end


# Loops through $dail_book
def display_cities
  puts "Options: "
  puts $dail_book.sort.each {|k,v| format_cities(k)}
end
```

**Output**

```
Options: 
Los Angeles
Miami
Minneapolis
New York
Omaha
Portland
San Diego
San Francisco
Seattle
Sioux Falls
los_angeles
212
miami
910
minneapolis
342
new_york
523
omaha
642
portland
234
san_diego
233
san_francisco
345
seattle
502
sioux_falls
543
```

**Question**

Why does the entire hash get returned at the end of the loop? What's happening?

Comment: just use `map` instead of `each`. See docs.

Comment: You can remove `format_cities` and add `puts $dail_book.keys.map { |citie| citie.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ') }.sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The each method returns the original enumerable object it was called upon, this is why you keep `puts`ing the entire hash after the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `puts` twice in your code:

```
def format_cities(k)
  puts ...         # <- here
end

def display_cities
  # ...
  puts $dail_bo... # <- and here
end
```

Try to keep your methods focused and modular. `display_cities` obviously *displays* something, so `puts` is expected here. `format_cities` on the other hand converts a value. It should not print anything.

Futhermore, its name (`..._cities`, plural) suggest that it is formatting  multiple cities at once, whereas it only formats *one* city at a time. It should therefore be called `format_city` (singular):

```
# removes the underscore, capitalizes each word
def format_city(city)
  city.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
```

Then, move the printing part into the display related method. But instead of printing the result of `each` (which returns the collection), move `puts` *into* the loop to print each formatted city name:

```
def display_cities
  puts "Options: "
  $dail_book.sort.each { |k, v| puts format_city(k) }
end
```